# Maintain a reference to HttpContext on different thread after request has completed

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, httpcontext

I've been trying to determine how safe it is to maintain a read-only reference to the HttpContext after a request has completed.  Specifically, I'm looking to grab a reference to HttpContext.Current when a request is executing, and then place a reference to the context into an in-memory queue for later evaluation (possibly up to a few seconds later) on a different thread.

Obviously, trying to work with and attempting to write to the context.Response won't work and I'm not particularly interested in that.  Instead, I'm interested in reading a few values on the context.Request property and a few other values from the context itself, e.g. context.Timestamp, context.Items, and maybe a few others.

Preliminary tests indicate I can do this, but I'm trying to program intentionally rather than by coincidence.  Can anyone point to any documentation (or perhaps a blog post or something from Jon Skeet) that indicates that references can be maintained after the HTTP request is complete?

Comment: Why not just copy the values you need? Faster, safer, etc.

Comment: I don't know exactly which values I will need.  In a worst case scenario, I suppose I could bulk copy the values to an HttpContextBase if necessary.

Comment: If you program by intention and not coincidence, you know which values you need. There is no "will need". :)

Comment: Why is not copying slower than copying?

Comment: The code is for a general messaging library, so I don't know which values may be needed off of the context.

Comment: If you don't know which values you will need, then you don't need any of them. When you need them, you will know.

Comment: One minor side effect I can see is that Ninject's Cache and Collect Weak Reference based lazy collection scheme would be defeated by this (but OOTB there's an automatic Release after request processing has been completed). IOW no direct impact there but an example of the sorts of chichanery and/or indirect impact on GC you might trigger by keeping a normally very short-lived object alive for an extended period

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't safe, but it has little to do with threading.

It's Http***Context***.Current. That's *context* as in "context of the current request".

Don't use this after the request is over!

The various IDisposable resources in the context will have been disposed of, so don't use them. Any number of other things that were valid during the request will not be valid because *the request is **over***.

Once you decide what parts of it you need, copy those parts and save them.

Comment: I'm looking at things like Request.QueryString, Request.Headers, perhaps even HttpContext.Items (which is really Hashtable under the hood).

Comment: Then copy those once you are certain that you need them.